# I want to show all my tables from my database to an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, api, server

I have 3 tables (services, practitioners, network) in my postgres database and I want them all to show in my API, but I got this error

> (node:21300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

and this is the only output I could get
[json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcvZr.png)

here is my code.

```js
const handler = (req, res, db, tableName)  => {
    try{
        db.select('*').from(tableName)
                    .then(data => {
                        if(data.length){
                            res.status(200).json({tableName: data});
                        }
                    })
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).json(err)
    }
}

const content = (req, res, db) => {
    handler(req, res, db, 'services')
    handler(req, res, db, 'practitioners')
}

module.exports = { content };
```

edit:
here's what I did from [Nabil Farhan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13685489/nabil-farhan)'s answer, and it's working just what I wanted. [screenCapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGK2f.png)

```js
const getData = async (db, tableName) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.select('*').from(tableName)
                      .then(data => {
                          resolve({[tableName]:data})
                      })
    });
}

const contentHandler = async (req, res, db) => {
    // get the argument from get request

    let allTable = [];

    const table_a = await getData(db, 'services');
    const table_b = await getData(db, 'practitioners');

    allTable.push(table_a);
    allTable.push(table_b);
    
    res.status(200).json({data: allTable});
}

module.exports = { contentHandler };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use promise like this:

```
async function getData(tableName) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    db.select("*")
      .from(tableName)
      .then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
      });
  });
}

async function run(){
    var allTable = [];

    const firstTable = await getData('testingDB');
    const secondTable = await getData('user');

    allTable.push(firstTable);
    allTable.push(secondTable);

    res.status(200).json({data: allTable});
}

run().then(() => {
    console.log("Finished!");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple potential issues here.
Unhandled Promise rejection:
Add a catch block after then (you can rethrow to put it in the existing catch block).

```
.then(data => {
      if(data.length){
           let responseData = {}
           responseData[tableName] = data
           res.status(200).json(responseData)
      }
 })
 .catch(err) {throw err}
```

`tableName` is also not going to be interpreted as variable, but as a literal property name, so I changed it to get what I think you were going for.

For the header error, you are setting the response twice, once for "services", then again for "practitioners". One possible solution is to remove the `res.status...` line from handler and use Promise.all in content and moving the response setting there:

```
 const content = (req, res, db) => {
    Promise.all(
      handler(req, res, db, 'services')
      handler(req, res, db, 'practitioners')
    )
    .then(allData => {
      //use reduce/Object.assign to combine the individual data objects
      allData.reduce((finalResponseData, data) => {
          if(!data.length) return finalResponseData
          Object.assign(finalResponseData, data)
    })
    .then(finalResponseData => res.status(200).json(finalResponseData)
    .catch(err) {res.status(400).json(err)}
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. Although it still has UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning. I can still use this as a reference on a future basis.
Thanks!